# How to access XML Spreadsheet format?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel

I would like to access the XML data which Excel is putting onto the clipboard.

Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5, C#

I know I could parse the XML document with XML functions, but probably there is a somewhat more simpler tool available.

Ideally, I'm looking for a function like `object GetCell(row, col)` which delivers the content at a specific location.

I only need to access table data.

Parsing is not so simple, because Excel skips empty rows and columns, and puts an index into the following cell.

Currently, we are using tabbed text format, but that has a lot of exchange problems (confused dot and comma, confused date formats, text interpreted as number, ...). The xml format is much more robust.

Below is an example how that XML format looks alike. This a grid area with 3 columns and 6 rows. Please note the different data formats and the empty cells and rows.

I would be mainly interested in parsing the `<table>`. All other is not of main interest.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Tabelle1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="6"
   ss:DefaultColumnWidth="60" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="117"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">2.2999999999999998</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2013-04-07T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Number as Text:</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">0123</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">next cell is empty</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">b</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">next 5 cells are all empty</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Index="6">
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">This is</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">the</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">last line</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Why are you not using XPath? Can you provide a short sample,so we can see the complexity of the data?

Comment: @DiableNoir Probably there is a more simpler solution. If there is none, then I'd of course use some of the built-in functions for xml processing.

Comment: I don't know about the clipboard format, but have you seen http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use XPath:
/Workbook/Worksheet[@ss:Name="Tabelle1"]//Row[2]//Cell[2]/Data

This will select the Data in Worksheet "Tabelle1", Row 2, Cell 2.